# Proving a vector operator identity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, vectors

> Consider the operator, $\mathbf{L} = -i\hbar\mathbf{r}\times \nabla$ where $i = \sqrt -1$. We need to prove that $\mathbf{L}\times\mathbf{L}f = i\hbar\mathbf{L}f$ , where $f$ is an arbitrary test function.

I tried this by simplifying the left hand side, using the properties of $\nabla$ but it doesn't seem to work, I get $-3\mathbf{r}\times\nabla f$ plus some other terms.

**Edit 1:**

Applying basic vector identities, I have reached the following result:
$\mathbf{L}\times\mathbf{L}f = 2i\mathbf{L}f + \mathbf{r}\times(\mathbf{r}\cdot\nabla)(\nabla f) $
(consider $\hbar = 1$)

I am not able to reduce the second term, any hints are appreciated.

Comment: This is better suited to Mathematics, but you should also show all work you've attempted so we can even see where you've gone wrong.

Comment: @Triatticus It was a lot of LaTex and I was too lazy to type :/

Comment: @Triatticus I think this is a fine question for physics, considering it's just quantum mechanics.

Comment: Yeah it might be motivated by QM but the main point of the question is pure mathematics, the result doesn't depend on the fact that it comes from physics so there is no physics concept to explain here

Comment: @Triatticus I have made some edits explaining my work, is there something else which I need to include?